# Access Master Page control (html: Input) from Content Page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, master-pages

I have an input control on Master Page where I store the window size that is returned by a javascript that runs onload. I need to access these controls from the content page but I can't make it work. To make things more visible and easier I use the input type "text". Once everything should work, I will switch this to type "hidden"

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="hiddenInputW" />
```

On the content page I am trying this to access the controls in the on page_load event.

```
HtmlInputText width = (HtmlInputText)Page.Master.FindControl("hiddenInputW");
HtmlInputText height = (HtmlInputText)Page.Master.FindControl("hiddenInputH");
```

the other option that didn't work was to create this method on the Masterpage:

```
public string WindowWidth
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToString(hiddenInputW.Value);
    }
}
```

and to access from the Content Page side (in page_load)

```
LabelTest.Text = Master.WindowWidth;
```

Both times the data is not passed to the content page.

I access the Content Page through a LinkButton and the code:

```
Response.Redirect("ProcessMap.aspx");
```

The Javascript that I use to get the window size is:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#hiddenInputW").val($(window).width());
$("#hiddenInputH").val($(window).height());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so as noted, read my comments. The issue is that the page is first rendered on the server, the code behind runs (but you can't get those hidden field values yet).

Then the page travels down to the browser, the page is rendered and displayed in the browser and THEN AND ONLY then does the js code run to set/get/grab the screen resolution stuff and save those values into a hidden field.

> You actually describe the behavior: the values can be grabbed on the pages first post-back. So how can I solve this

As noted, any button click - you NOT limited to the first post back, but in fact any and all subsequent post-backs will allow you to get the values. And YES, this includes the use of a link button. So, if you happy to accept grabbing those values on some form of post-back - including a link button - then fine.

You CAN get the values without a post back if you wish. What you would do is in place of that js code that runs client side first time, is that js code could run and call a web method that passes the values to the server and you could then say save the values in session(). So either you grab those values on additional post-backs (first one, or everyone AFTER that first page load, or you have that js code run and do a AJAX call to a web method on the server which could then say save the values into session().

So, you have the above two choices:

```
Get the values in the hidden fields on any postback that occurs on that page.

Use a AJAX call which does not require a post-back, but such calls of course don't 
do a post-back, so you can't get/grab/see in code behind the controls on the FIRST
page load since they are still sitting on the users desktop.
However a AJAX call does allow you to pass values to the server, and thus as a
result you can/could have this information available from that point on, which
of course means on ANY new post-back, which of course is quite much the first 
example and use case anyway!
```

So EVEN if we do use a AJAX call, and web method?
Then now your code beind can see/use those values, but you ONLY EVER get to run such code on some user interaction that causes a post back anyway!

(unless you just looking to log the screen size, and client browser into a database one time - this would of course suggest that a AJAX call would be better. It depends on what you need that information for, and how you going to use it? If you just logging this information - then yes, the AJAX call would be better.

If your application needs this information, then little advantages to using a AJAX call helps, since any and all code you run on that site WILL be a result of a post-back anyway, so now we back to square one anyway.

the simple matter is you can't get these values on the first page load. But then again, that may well not matter, and any future use of such values will be the result of a post-back anyway.

Comment: Thank you Albert, I finally surrender and will work with a fixed window size. I could make it work for the scenario that you load the masterpage with its default content page first, where no size specific rendering is required. During that step the size is grabbed and can be used on the next postback when I enter the content pages. BUT i wasn't able to access those content page right from the start and getting the size on the first rendering as you predicted. Thanks for explaining those points anyway